# Local variables: Pascal or Camel Casing?

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

In *VB.NET*, what is the MS standard for naming local variables, Camel or Pascal casing?

For example

```
 Sub X()
      Dim myVariable As Integer
 End sub
```

or

```
Sub X()
  Dim MyVariable As Integer
End Sub
```

Comment: Given the examples, this question is incorrectly titled. It appears the question is intended to address the naming of **fields**, not **local variables**. (C# programmers may also be interested in this question...that is what brought me here.)

Comment: Concerning the `Dim` keyword, from [Access Levels in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx): "At the module level, the **Dim** statement without any access level keywords is equivalent to a **Private** declaration. However, you might want to use the **Private** keyword to make your code easier to read and interpret."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) (under Names of Fields):

> The naming guidelines for fields apply to static public and protected fields. You should not define public or protected instance fields. For more information, see Field Design.
>
> **Do use Pascal casing in field names.**
>
> **Do name fields with nouns or noun phrases.**
>
> **Do not use a prefix for field names. For example, do not use g_ or s_ to distinguish static versus non-static fields**

---

The guidelines say nothing about **private** fields, though all examples seem to be using **camel casing**.

Nor do the guidelines say anything about local variables, though all examples also seem to be using **camel casing**.

Comment: Pascal for "Field Names?" Are you saying that "MyVariable" is a "field name" and hence should use Pascal casing? I prefer this, as this way I can distingguish local fields such as MyVariable from param variables. I can already discern both of these from Module level variables, which are prefixed with an "_", a controversial convention since VB is not case sensitive. Comments?

Comment: @Valika - this is from Microsoft. Note that the pascal case guidelines are for **static public and protected** fields.

Comment: But these guidelines don't apply to local variables at all? Fields aren't local variables, whether they are public or private. The guidelines are for publicly visible elements of class libraries. The guidelines do recommend camel casing for parameter names - which still aren't local variables, but arguably the closest thing to them in the guidelines. The [book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321545613?ie=UTF8&tag=bradabramsblo-20&link_code=wql&camp=212361&creative=380601) version of the guidelines has some discussion of naming conventions for private fields but nothing on local variables.

Comment: @MarkJ - quite right. The guidelines say nothing about local variables either. Answer amended.

Comment: RE: Concerning the naming of **local variables**: In [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx), the following local variable names appear in the examples: `longString`, `orderLog`, `closeItem`, `htmlDoc` and `seattleCustomers`. So indeed, it appears that Microsoft is silently recommending the use of **camelCase** for the naming of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that VB.NET users tend to use Pascal casing, but C# users tend to use Camel case.  I think Camel Case has many advantages over Pascal casing.

It gives you the ability to immediately discern between global and local variables, reserves _ items for private variables, and Pascal cased items for properties or global variables.

You combine that with additional information in the variable the control type for ASPX pages, i.e., btnOK, and you get a very nice list in Intellisense based on control type and scope.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the following:

```
Sub X()
  Dim variable As Integer
End Sub
```

The [Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx) state:

> Do not use "My" or "my" as part of a variable name. This practice
>   creates confusion with the My objects.

I know that wasn't your question but thought I should point it out as I had just read it.

As Oded states, the examples on the [Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx) page are all using camelCase.